# How to iterate over a vue getter

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I have this getter **this.getHouseTypes** it returns an array with objects from the vuex store.

But now i want to append 1 item to the array in the shortest way so i was thinking about **...** like:

```
return [...this.getHouseTypes, newObject];
```

But that gives me an error:

```
Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Does anyone know why this is ?

Any help is welcome !

EDIT: but in the vue inspector it shows the new array with this.getHouseTypes and newObject in it

Comment: Where do you want to add the `newObject`? in a component or to the store?

Comment: @Anuga in a component in a computed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like you should do something like this:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      houseTypes: [],
    }
  }
  // ...
  computed: {
    addHouseType(newType) {
      let houseTypes = this.getHouseTypes();

      this.houseTypes = this.houseTypes.concat(houseTypes).push(newType);

      return this.houseTypes;
    },
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapGetters([
      'getHouseTypes',
      // ...
    ])
  }
}
```

Have a `data` variable `houseTypes`, which is an empty array in the beginning.

Mix your `getters`, with your `computed`.

Have a `computed` that adds values to the local `houseTypes` and merges the `store` state.

Depending on what you are doing, you might want to split the adding and retrieving the new `array`.